# Inheriting properties of a separate class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am instantiating a class inside another one:

```
class A(F):

  def __init__(self):
    return

  b = B()
```

Class B also inherits class F:

```
class B(F):
      def __init__(self):
        return
```

There are properties of F which have been defined in class A, which I need to access inside class B. (a MySQL connection and a logging handler.)

I would like B to have the properties which have been set to F, when they were instantiated initially in A, so I can use the logging/mysql handlers inside B without re-instantiating them.

How can I go about this? Sorry if the question is unclear.

Comment: A inherits from F, so F can't have properties defined in A. Did you have the correct order in your code?

Comment: It would be much clearer what you're really trying to do with real names for the functions an classes.

Answer (score 1):

Put the stuff you want to share in `F` and both `A` and `B` will be able to share it. Eg

```
class F(object):
    def useful(self):
        pass

class A(F):
    def something(self):
        self.useful()

class B(F):
    def something_else(self):
        self.useful()
```